# Visual Studio - "{ }" settings

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

Seriously, I don't know what to google. Here's the thing, I like this Java-like code writing:

```
if (condition == true) {
   doSomeStuff();
}
```

But VisualStudio "helps" me with its own "style", which I don't like and I am unable to change (after rather big time of desperate checking all settings :/)

```
if (condition == true)
{
  DoStuff();
}
```

I obviously want the "{" char to be in same line where condition is ...

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 professional.

Comment: Does the 2008 way work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561/visual-studio-2005-2008-how-to-keep-first-curly-brace-on-same-line

Comment: Why do you want to do it the *wrong* way?  ;)

Comment: Those are called curly braces or brackets.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor >  [Language, i.e.: C#] > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines

This is where you can set your new line options for braces.

See the image below for more clarification.

[image: menu]

Comment: I always forget this.

Comment: For Visual Studio Code go File -> Preferences -> Settings and under Extensions choose the language you want to change properties. Search for  `Clang_format_fallback Style` (e.g.: for C++ `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style`) and change the value from `Visual Studio` to `Google`

Comment: In Visual Studio in 2018 (Community version on a Mac, 8.0.5): Preferences -> Source Code -> Code Formatting -> [Language (e.g. C#)] -> Change the Tab to C# Format -> Click "Edit".

Then change the category to "New Lines" and you get all the options, which you may want to turn off.

Answer (score 7):

Tools -> Options ...

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/158/capturejo.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/158/capturejo.png)

Answer (score 6):

**Text Editor** > **C#** > **Formatting** > **New Lines** > **New line options for braces**

- Uncheck `Place open brace on new line for control blocks`.
- Probably want to uncheck `put else on newline` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Visual Stuio 2008, so I'm not sure that it's exactly the same in VS 2010:

Go to the `Tools` menu and open `Options`. Make sure that the `Show all settings` checkbox is checked. Open the `Text Editor` node and then the node for the language you want to change the setting for. Open the `Formatting` node and select the `New Lines` node. Here you can change when new lines are added to the code.

After installing Visual Studio I go in there and uncheck every option in the `New Lines` section.

Answer (score 0):

Worth knowing is that Steve Horn's (and others) answer works even for other languages as they seem to appear to not have the same settings-layout. I did the changes as described in his post and it worked for my C++ projects as well.