# Adjust visual studio curly braces placements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I'm coding in C# using visual studio, the curly brace gets a new line of their own. I don't like this because it's visually unappealing to me and it's wasting a line just for a curly brace. I would like it to automatically stay on the same line as my code.

I want to go from

```
while (counter < 100)
{
    doStuff();
}
```

to

```
while (counter < 100){
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Please visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561/visual-studio-2005-2012-how-to-keep-first-curly-brace-on-same-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options.

In the opened window go to Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines

At the top, "place open brace on new lines" should be selected. Deselect it and it should be done.

There is also a preview on the bottom, you can play with more options to adjust formatting to your liking.