# VSCode format curly brackets on the same line c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, curly-braces

When using the Format Document command I'd like to change how the code formats.
I'm completely new to VSCode and I'm still having trouble navigating the settings, so easy to understand replies would be very helpful.
Currently the code is formatting like this:

```
void start ()
{
//Do stuff here
}
```

I want it to look like:

```
void start () {
//Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2005/2012: How to keep first curly brace on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561/visual-studio-2005-2012-how-to-keep-first-curly-brace-on-same-line)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561/visual-studio-2005-2012-how-to-keep-first-curly-brace-on-same-line) is what you're looking for

Comment: @MatthewSchlachter VS Code is not the same as Visual Studio

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/243

Comment: Worth noting that common C# convention is to have the braces on a new line so you may be better off getting used to it the way it is now.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on in that post, as I stated in the post, I'm new to VSCode, and I dont know how to access the json files.

I've been using curly brackets on the same line for 2 years now, it's not something that I'll change cause to me it looks way neater.

Comment: No problem you sticking to whatever you prefer, that's fine. I'm just suggesting that most people do it the other way and if you work in a team of developers, it's vital everyone has a similar style. My guess is that you work on your own?

Comment: Even if you work on your own *now*, if you think that you may well work on a team doing C# work in the future, I'd suggest it's worth getting used to more common formatting conventions (and naming conventions - `Start` rather than `start`).

Comment: Could I just get help with the question that I've asked instead of being told how to format my work that would be great.

@JonSkeet I know how to use naming conventions, for the sake of an example, I didn't bother using proper naming conventions

Comment: You've [already been given help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136015/vscode-format-curly-brackets-on-the-same-line-c-sharp#comment85277009_49136015), these comments are additional suggestions that you can do with as you please. There's really no need to get upset about it. We're all friends here.

Comment: @Gordoxgrey: Given that you're going against the normal formatting conventions, it's hardly much of a stretch to think you might be going against naming conventions too. The lesson to learn is that when you're writing a question, it's worth following the normal conventions you would in your code, to avoid causing unnecessary distractions.

Comment: Ok a few things from that link that I was sent. 
1. How do I install Omnisharp?
2. Where is a .json file located? 
3. How do I edit a .json file?
4. If Omnisharp is built into VSCode, how do I edit the settings for it?

Comment: So that's a whole bunch of questions, and I'm afraid you're going to have to spend some time learning that for yourself. If you've been debugging C# code though, chances are that you already have OmniSharp installed as it's just an extension.

Comment: Did you read the blog post linked from the GitHub issue? https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I read through that blog, but it's out of date, I can't find any of the files or folders relating to omnisharp on my system.

Answer (score 68):

I have found this simple solution for VScode !

Just create a file called **omnisharp.json** at the root of your project and paste the following JSON :

```
{
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": false,
        "NewLineForElse": false,
        "NewLineForCatch": false,
        "NewLineForFinally": false
    }
}
```

I found the solution here:
https://medium.com/@wearetherock/visual-studio-code-c-put-the-opening-brace-on-the-same-line-as-the-statement-a98c552a544b

Comment: Optionally, for mac users you can make this a global setting for vs code by putting the config in a file at %USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json. More info here - https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/

Comment: This also works for GNU/Linux users (file located at `~/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json`, same content). Thanks!

Comment: And also on Windows in %USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json

Comment: Don't forget to restart omnisharp after otherwise it won't work right away.

Comment: This should have been the default from the get go :)

Comment: Note: For vscode version 1.25.1+ `./omnisharp.json` is overridden by configuration in `.editorconfig`. This can be disabled by adding `"omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": false` to `./.vscode/settings.json`.

Comment: @adc If you have an .editorconfig that defines that, why do you want to disable .editorconfig support? Someone, either yourself or your teammates, defined that configuration. It sounds silly to go against your own configuration - just change the appropriate .editorconfig configuration.

Comment: any solution described above doesn't work for me on `VsCode 1.74.3`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was configuring a unity project I maintain for the c# code style I prefer. This was the only way I found to get the editor to behave as I intended. Thought it might help other people in the same boat.

Comment: not working for VSCode 1.84.2

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

- Create a `.editorconfig` file in the project root with the following content:

```
#  CSharp formatting rules:
[*.cs]
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
```

- Restart Omnisharp.

Comment: didn't work for vscode 1.84.2

Comment: This works and is the only solution compatible with the latest C# Dev Kit that replaces Omnisharp.

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows + VSCode 1.25.1+**

1. Open a folder and paste **%USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/** in the address bar to enter the current user's folder.
2. Create the **omnisharp.json** file with the contents mentioned above.
3. In VSCode open the Command Pallet by Ctrl+Shift+p
4. Search for **Open User Settings (JSON)**
5. Add below line and save the file

   "omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": false
6. Again open the Command Pallet by Ctrl+Shift+p
7. Search for **Restart OmniSharp**

Thanks to [Pini Cheyni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773972/pini-cheyni), [Karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442840/karlsson), and [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5767817/adc)

Comment: Why would you disable editorConfig support? Sounds much smarter to just edit the file to your preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Camilo. I personally don't prefer that solution since it's project-based and the .editorConfig is a project file not a global VSCode settings. Since we're working on multiple projects, we prefer to set these configs globally through the VSCode settings so it applies to all my working projects on my machine.

Comment: Mac users can also follow from step 2 if omnisharp.json is not working for them

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define an `omnisharp.json` for every C# project that you have, a good alternative is this VS Code extension: [C# Curly Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ironcutter24.cscurlyformatter).

It was the solution for me that didn't want to define such config files for every C# based project that I had.