# Is there anyway to get VS Code to auto format curly brackets on new line for C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formatting, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to setup vscode to auto format the curly brackets to go on new lines. I recently had to switch from visual studio to vscode and trying to get it to function like i had my visual studio so i can fully get back to my usual work flow. Ive posts about some extensions that are sopposed to do this but they either dotn function right or are no longer available. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line)

Comment: Thats a solution for javascript, im using c# and it doesnt have those same options

Comment: https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/formatting-curly-braces-on-the-same-line-in-c-in-vscode-c4937e1c215f

Comment: I had the same issue, and answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195410/13177011).

Answer (score 0):

To make VSCode add a new line for opening curly brackets, Create a file named `omnisharp.json` in the root of your Unity project (beside your Assets folder) with the following content and then restart VSCode.

```
{
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers": true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": true,
        "NewLineForElse": true,
        "NewLineForCatch": true,
        "NewLineForFinally": true
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).